# Reduce consecutive duplicate patterns in list to single occurence

Tags: c#, algorithm, pattern-matching

Please suggest an approach or algorithm reference for the following problem.

Requirements:

- The patterns need to be consecutive.
- If, after the first set of reductions more can be done, then they should be applied further
- Please don't suggest Regex solutions because in my case I have to reduce some lists
- The resulting list must be the shortest possible one
- For the same input it must always produce the same reduction

Ex:

1. ABBABBB (B in BB and Bin BBB match the reduction pattern) => ABAB (AB match the reduction pattern) => AB
2. ABCDBCDA (BCD match the reduction pattern) => ABCDA
3. ABC => ABC
4. ABBA => ABA
5. ABCBCBCBC (the pattern could be BC or BCBC, pick the shortest one: BC) => ABC
6. ABCDBC => ABCDBC

Comment: This sounds exactly like homework without any initial effort on your part...

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static List<T> removePatterns<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        List<T> cleaned = new List<T>();
        List<T> pattern = new List<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            cleaned.Add(list[i]);
            pattern.Add(list[i]);
            // check if a pattern can be found ahead, increase pattern size slowly until something can be found
            int patternSize = -1;
            for (patternSize = 1; patternSize < pattern.Count + 1; patternSize++)
            {
                List<T> currentPattern = pattern.Skip(pattern.Count - patternSize).ToList();
                Boolean matches = true;
                for (int o = 0; o < currentPattern.Count() && matches; o++)
                    matches = i + 1 + o < list.Count && list[i + 1 + o].Equals(currentPattern[o]);
                if (matches)
                {
                    pattern = new List<T>();
                    i += currentPattern.Count;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (cleaned.Count != list.Count)
            return removePatterns(cleaned);
        return cleaned;
    }

    static void test(String list, String expected)
    {
        String result = String.Join("", removePatterns<String>(list.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList()).ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(list + " => " + result + " = " + expected);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Equals(expected) ? "Passed" : "Failed");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test("ABBABBB", "AB");
        test("ABCDBCDA", "ABCDA");
        test("ABC", "ABC");
        test("ABBA", "ABA");
        test("ABCBCBCBC", "ABC");
        test("ABCDBC", "ABCDBC");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This is what i made up from scratch. For the test cases it works as expected. But it may contain errors.